# Saving SimpleXMLElement as an xml file node attachment in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have my DOMDocument saved as $xml.

I have the node loaded, I also have a custom field i've made which is called 'field_xml_file'.

But I can't quite seem to get how to save the file and insert it into the node.

I currently have this:

```
$fileName = 'file.xml';
$file = file_save_data($xml, 'public://', $fileName);
$newRevision->field_xml_file[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = (array)$file;
node_save($node);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$fileName is not supposed to be third parameter. Change that line to:

```
$file = file_save_data($xml, 'public://'.$fileName);
```

second parameter is full file name, using drupal stream wrappers.

also, if this is literally code you are using, you need to change $newRevision to $node in order to save changes

Comment: Whoa, sorry, I added the $node part myself, it's supposed to be $newRevision.

I'll see what happens using your suggestion.

It returned this error:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048

Comment: i believe you should only pass file id as reference, so: $newRevision->field_xml_file[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['fid'] = $file->fid; hope this helps. also if you want to update node, you need to load it first $node = node_load({nid}); if not read up how to initialize new node class.